# When to use /dev/random vs /dev/urandom

Tags: devices, random

Should I use `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`?

In which situations would I prefer one over the other?

Comment: See also [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key)

Comment: ***[cross-posted (and locked) at crypto.se](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/41595/12164)***

Comment: https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/

Answer (score 161, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `/dev/urandom` for most practical purposes.

The longer answer depends on the flavour of Unix that you're running.

#### Linux

[Historically, `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` were introduced at the same time.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323610/143394)

As @DavidSchwartz pointed out [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323610/143394), using `/dev/urandom` is preferred in the vast majority of cases. He and others also provided a link to the excellent [Myths about `/dev/urandom`](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) article which I recommend for further reading.

In summary:

- The [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) is misleading.
- Both are fed by the *same* [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) to generate randomness ([diagrams 2 and 3](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/))
- `/dev/random` blocks when it runs out of entropy,
  so reading from `/dev/random` can halt process execution.
- The amount of entropy is conservatively estimated, but not counted
- `/dev/urandom` will never block.
- In rare cases very shortly after boot, the [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) may not have had enough entropy to be properly seeded and `/dev/urandom` may not produce high-quality randomness.
- Entropy running low is not a problem if the CSPRNG was initially seeded properly.
- The CSPRNG is being constantly re-seeded.
- In Linux 4.8 and onward, `/dev/urandom` does not deplete the entropy pool (used by `/dev/random`) but uses the CSPRNG output from upstream.
- Use `/dev/urandom`.

**Exceptions to the rule**

In the Cryptography Stack Exchange's [When to use `/dev/random` over `/dev/urandom` in Linux](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/41595/40609)
@otus [gives two use cases](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41596/40609):

1. Shortly after boot on a low entropy device, if enough entropy has not yet been generated to properly seed `/dev/urandom`.
2. [Generating a one-time pad with information theoretic security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/35031/40609)

If you're worried about (1), you can [check the entropy available in `/dev/random`](https://serverfault.com/q/529750/322507).

If you're doing (2) you'll know it already :)

Note: You can [check if reading from /dev/random will block](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/243127/143394), but beware of possible race conditions.

**Alternative: use neither!**

@otus also pointed out that the [`getrandom()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) system will read from `/dev/urandom` and only block if the initial seed entropy is unavailable.

There are [issues with changing `/dev/urandom` to use `getrandom()`](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/10/21/982), but it is conceivable that a new `/dev/xrandom` device is created based upon `getrandom()`.

#### macOS

It doesn't matter, as
[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#macOS_and_iOS):

> macOS uses 160-bit [Yarrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarrow_algorithm) based on SHA1. There is no difference between /dev/random and /dev/urandom; both behave identically. Apple's iOS also uses Yarrow.

#### FreeBSD

It doesn't matter, as [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#FreeBSD):

> `/dev/urandom` is just a link to `/dev/random` and only blocks until properly seeded.

This means that after boot, FreeBSD is smart enough to wait until enough seed entropy has been gathered before delivering a never-ending stream of random goodness.

#### NetBSD

Use `/dev/urandom`, assuming your system has read at least once from `/dev/random` to ensure proper initial seeding.

The [rnd(4) manpage says](https://www.netbsd.org/%7Eriastradh/tmp/20141116/rnd.html):

> `/dev/urandom` never blocks.
>
> `/dev/random` sometimes blocks. Will block early at boot if the
> system's state is known to be predictable.
>
> Applications should read from `/dev/urandom` when they need randomly
> generated data, e.g. cryptographic keys or seeds for simulations.
>
> Systems should be engineered to judiciously read at least once from
> `/dev/random` at boot before running any services that talk to the
> internet or otherwise require cryptography, in order to avoid
> generating keys predictably.

Comment: _BSD: Use `/dev/urandom`_ - Except there is no such thing as a `/dev/urandom` on OpenBSD.  OpenBSD has `/dev/arandom`, but you aren't supposed to use it, you should use the `arc4random(3)` function instead.  Perhaps advise about random devices and functions should be left to people who actually understand what all that is about?

Comment: @SatoKatsura Good catch. Updated to FreeBSD to reflect the quote. How would you propose to determine who those people are?

Comment: Academic qualifications?  Peer-reviewed work?

Comment: "In rare cases very shortly after boot, the CSPRNG may not have had enough entropy to be properly seeded and /dev/urandom may not produce high-quality randomness." and "Shortly after boot on a low entropy device, if enough entropy has not yet been generated to properly seed /dev/urandom."  -- How soon after boot are we talking about here?

Comment: Good question. It's not a clock-time, it's determined by the amount of entropy gathered, generated by things like network traffic. I've asked a question based on this [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334960/check-if-dev-urandom-has-been-proplery-seeded-in-linux).

Comment: *"`/dev/random` blocks when it runs out of entropy"* - On Linux, it depends how you open the device. If `open` flags include `O_NONBLOCK` then it won't block. If there is no entropy then the call will return immediate and indicate 0 bytes read.

Comment: Also, be careful with [dd and /dev/random](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33009/23683) if you're trying to generate key files or similar.  If you're trying to use `/dev/random`, prefer `head` over `dd` - `head -c 4096 < /dev/random > crypt.key`.

Comment: @RyanJ why is that preferable to `dd bs=4k`?

Comment: @TomHale The behavior is less surprising IMO.  If `/dev/random` is only (ex:) 60 bytes, `dd` will give you a 60 byte file.  Using `head` in the same scenario will probably look like it's hanging forever.  Neither is doing what you want, but, at least for me, it's more obvious that `head` isn't doing what was expected.

Comment: [Updated link to the Myths about /dev/urandom article.](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/)

Comment: 2022/02 Linux update: soon both will behave exactly the same after about the first second after Linux boots -- https://lwn.net/Articles/884875/

Answer (score 10):

This is somewhat of a "me too" answer, but it strengthens Tom Hale's recommendation. It squarely applies to Linux.

- Use `/dev/urandom`
- Don't use `/dev/random`

According to Theodore Ts'o on the Linux Kernel Crypto mailing list, `/dev/random` has been deprecated for a decade. From [Re: [RFC PATCH v12 3/4] Linux Random Number Generator](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/7/20/993):

> Practically no one uses /dev/random.  It's essentially a deprecated
>   interface; the primary interfaces that have been recommended for well
>   over a decade is /dev/urandom, and now, getrandom(2).

We regularly test `/dev/random` and it suffers frequent failures. The test performs the three steps: (1) drain `/dev/random` by asking for 10K bytes in non-blocking mode; (2) request 16 bytes in blocking mode (3) attempt to compress the block to see if its random (poor man's test). The test takes minutes to complete.

The problem is so bad on Debain systems (i686, x86_64, ARM, and MIPS) we asked GCC Compile Farm to install the `rng-tools` package for their test machines. From [Install rng-tools on gcc67 and gcc68](https://lists.tetaneutral.net/pipermail/cfarm-users/2017-July/000030.html):

> I would like to request that rng-tools be installed on gcc67 and
>   gcc68. They are Debian systems, and /dev/random suffers entropy
>   depletion without rng-tools when torture testing libraries which
>   utilize the device.

The BSDs and OS X appear OK. The problem is definitely Linux.

---

It might also be worth mentioning Linux does not log generator failures. They did not want the entries filling up the system log. To date, most failures are silent and go undetected by most users.

The situation should be changing shortly since the kernel is going to print at least one failure message. From [[PATCH] random: silence compiler warnings and fix race](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/6/20/191) on the kernel crypto mailing list:

> > Specifically, I added `depends on DEBUG_KERNEL`. This means that these
> >     useful warnings will only poke other kernel developers. This is probably
> >     exactly what we want. If the various associated developers see a warning
> >     coming from their particular subsystem, they'll be more motivated to
> >     fix it. Ordinary users on distribution kernels shouldn't see the
> >     warnings or the spam at all, since typically users aren't using
> >     DEBUG_KERNEL.
>
> I think it is a bad idea to suppress all messages from a security
>   engineering point of view.
>
> Many folks don't run debug kernels. Most of the users who want or need
>   to know of the issues won't realize its happening. Consider, the
>   reason we learned of systemd's problems was due to dmesg's.
>
> Suppressing all messages for all configurations cast a wider net than
>   necessary. Configurations that could potentially be detected and fixed
>   likely will go unnoticed. If the problem is not brought to light, then
>   it won't be fixed.
>
> I feel like the kernel is making policy decisions for some
>   organizations. For those who have hardware that is effectively
>   unfixable, then organization has to decide what to do based on their
>   risk adversity. They may decide to live with the risk, or they may
>   decide to refresh the hardware. However, without information on the
>   issue, they may not even realize they have an actionable item.

The compromise eventually reached later in the thread was at least one dmesg per calling module.

Answer (score 9):

Traditionally, the only difference between `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` is what happens when kernel thinks there is no entropy in the system - `/dev/random` fails closed, `/dev/urandom` fails open. Both drivers were sourcing entropy from `add_disk_randomness()`, `add_interrupt_randomness()`, and `add_input_randomness()`. See `/drivers/char/random.c` for specifics.

*Edited to add: As of Linux 4.8 `/dev/urandom` was reworked to use CSPRNG.*

So when should you fail closed? For any kind of cryptographic use, specifically seeding DRBG. There is a very good paper explaining consequences of using `/dev/urandom` when generating RSA keys and not having enough entropy. Read [Mining Your Ps and Qs](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final228.pdf).

Comment: it's not longer yarrow on macOS : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362531/does-macos-still-use-yarrow-as-its-cryptographically-secure-pseudorandom-number/365529#365529