# Check if /dev/urandom has been properly seeded in Linux

Tags: linux, random

[Myths about `/dev/urandom`](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) says that in rare cases very shortly after boot, the [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) may not have had enough entropy to be properly seeded and `/dev/urandom` may not produce high-quality randomness.

How do I check to ensure that `/dev/urandom` has been properly seeded?

Comment: Many popular distros save a random seed upon shutdown, so there should be sufficient entropy when you are using one of those. Which distro are you using?

Comment: Manjaro. I'm getting `uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)` at kernel boot.

Comment: Try cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail

Comment: Good thought... how much `/dev/random` entropy available is needed to properly seed `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: This depends on what you are doing and how concerned you are with security. Typically, you should Really Care about seeding your cryptographic random number generators. Assuming you are using OpenSSL's DRBG based on AES256-CTR with random nonce, you should have no less than 384 bits of entropy after you finished booting.

Comment: /dev/random and /dev/urandom are not seeded off each other. Depending on your kernel version, they are seeded from add_disk_randomness(), add_interrupt_randomness(), and add_input_randomness(). See drivers/char/random.c for details.