# Remove space and symbols from grep output

Tags: grep

I'm trying to generate a random password with this small script

`#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $PASSWORD ]; then
PASSWORD=$(date | md5sum | grep '[a-zA-Z1-9]')
fi`

But this results in a result like :

15d020e6e8e6038ffb027323401ca9a9 -

My password field cannot have any empty space or symbols, I want to use standard bash commands because this is will be executed in bare docker environments.

How do I fix this? I tried grep -o but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to parse out the actual digest out from the output of `md5sum`:

1. `grep -E -o '[[:alnum:]]+'`, this would return the alphanumeric part of the `md5sum` output, but would also give you any filename bits if present in the output (not in the case presented in the question, as the filename is `-`, standard input).
2. `cut -d ' ' -f 1`, this would simply return the bit of the output before the first space character.  This is arguably the most common way to get at the "naked" MD5 digest string.
3. Variations on the `cut` theme includes `awk '{ print $1 }'` and similar things.

For password generation, I would suggest using `pwgen` rather than an MD5 digest, mostly because an MD5 digest, unless computed over random data, is not random.

A hack would be to use something like

```
tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | dd bs=1 count=32 2>/dev/null
```

This would extract a stream of alphanumeric characters from `/dev/urandom` and `dd` would cut the stream off after 32 such characters.  Instead of `dd`, one could also use `head -c 32`.

Or, using `md5sum` (in this case over 1Kb of random data from `/dev/urandom`):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1k count=1 | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

But really, just install and use `pwgen`.

See also [When to use /dev/random vs /dev/urandom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom)

Comment: accepted for being more complete. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
PASSWORD=$(date | md5sum | grep -o '[a-z0-9]*')
```

man grep:

```
>    Repetition
>        A  regular  expression  may  be  followed  by one of several repetition
>        operators:
>        ?      The preceding item is optional and matched at most once.
>        *      The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
```

ps.: this is very unsecure password generation. Better to use [pwgen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen) or [mkpasswd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkpasswd).

Comment: Why would this be insecure ? It is 32 characters long, with a high number of entropy, and it's not necessary to install anything else in my docker

Comment: 86400 variations  per day is a very weak entropy.

Comment: realistically what is the chance of this backfiring in me? do you have a alternative that uses bare *nix commands?

Comment: @Freedo `tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | dd bs=1 count=16 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks so much! this place is awesome

Comment: Note that with the ast-open implementation of `grep` (one of the few that support that non-standard `-o` option and only recently), that would run indefinitely as that `[a-z0-9]*` regexp matches the empty string.